# VF Pie Chart with two data points

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, visualforce-charting

Is it possible to have two data points(two different custom fields ie. Data1field & Datafield) in a single pie chart?  Currently there are no errors but pie chart doesn't show.

```
public class PieChartController {
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
    List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    List<Treatment__c> post = new List<Treatment__c>();

    String soql = 'SELECT Name,Data1field__c, Datafield__c   FROM Treatment__c ';
    post = Database.Query(soql);

    for(Treatment__c temp: post)
    {
        Decimal d1 = temp.Data1field__c;
        Decimal d = temp.Datafield__c;
        if(d1 == null) d1 = 0;
        if(d == null) d = 0;
        data.add(new PieWedgeData(d1,d));
    }
    System.debug(data);

    return data;
}

// Wrapper class
public class PieWedgeData {

    public Decimal data1 { get; set; }
    public Decimal data { get; set; }

    public PieWedgeData(Decimal data1, Decimal data) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data = data;
    }
  }
}
```